# The most popular means of transport is the car/a car - which article?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Which article is correct in this sentence?

```
The most popular means of transport is the car/a car
```

As far as I understand, when we mean the invention itself in general, we use 'the', but 'a' implies each individual car. Considering that, I'd use 'the', but my Google search showed that 'a' is actually more frequently used.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: I would use _the_ too, for the reason you give.

Comment: @KateBunting thank you!